# How to show second row in first row as a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL table called Test. Which has only two row of data as shown below:
[image: Select * from Test Result]

**Note** *There is only two note either 1 or 2 and Name can be anything. Note order is not sequential it can be inserted Name related to Note 1 only or Note 2 only*

I need the result as the following image:

[image: Expected result]

**Note** *If only Note value 1 records in the table then ID2, Name2, and Note2 always should be null.*

Can somebody please help me to achieve this with SQL query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your data/question is a little thin.  Can you show us what happens if there are more records than 2 (say 5-10) ?

Comment: Pivot Table :  https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample/

Comment: All records which have note value 2 should come as Id2, Name2 and Note2 and records which has Note value 1, records details should come under Id1, Name 1 and Note 1. Updated questions

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 select a.Id as Id1, a.Name as Name1, a.Note as Note1,
    b.Id as Id2, b.Name as Name2, b.Note as Note2  
    from Test as a
    left join Test as b on b.Id = 2
    where a.Id = 1
```

editted as the below comment

```
 select a.Id as Id1, a.Name as Name1, a.Note as Note1,
    b.Id as Id2, b.Name as Name2, b.Note as Note2  
    from Test as a
    left join Test as b on b.Id = a.Id+1
    where a.Id % 2 ! = 0
```

Comment: It is my bad. I had given only two row. But if we have more than two row then above query is not working. Please check updated questions.

Comment: i replied on this 'Which has only two row of data as shown below'

Comment: Yes it works, when Note 2 records always inserted immediately after Note 1. I think I had not given complete information in the questions. Thanks all your help!!

Comment: Below solution works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/50907446/3305457

Answer (score 1):

If you want *singe* row then you can do something like :

```
select 
      max(case when seq = 1 then id end) as id1, 
      max(case when seq = 1 then Name end) as Name1, 
      max(case when seq = 1 then Note end) as Note1, 
      max(case when seq = 2 then id end) as id2, 
      max(case when seq = 2 then Name end) as Name2,
      max(case when seq = 2 then Note end) as Note2
from (select *, 1+(row_number() over (order by id)-1) % 2 as seq
      from test
     ) t
group by (id-seq);
```

Comment: It is my bad. I had given only two row. But if we have more than two row then above query is not working. Please check updated questions

Comment: @NeerajKumarSingh. . . You can use `row_number()` in `subquery`.

Answer (score 1):

You can build subsets with only the records for `note = 1` or `note = 2` including a `row_number()` and `FULL JOIN` them on the `row_number()`.

```
SELECT x.id id1,
       x.name name1,
       x.note note1,
       y.id id2,
       y.name name2,
       y.note note2
       FROM (SELECT t.id,
                    t.name,
                    t.note,
                    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t.id) row#
                    FROM test t
                    WHERE t.note = 1) x
            FULL JOIN (SELECT t.id,
                              t.name,
                              t.note,
                              row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t.id) row#
                              FROM test t
                              WHERE t.note = 2) y
                      ON x.row# = y.row#;
```

Comment: This works for my all scenario. Thanks @Sticky Bit.!!